# If I make a piece of code in which each thread modifies completely different parts of an array, will that maintain cache coherency?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

So I am making some parallel code using OpenMP (but this question should be reasonably applicable to other frameworks), in which I have an array of objects:

```
std::vector<Body> bodies;
```

And then I do a little parallel loop to do some things to the `bodies`.  At the start of this parallel section, a team of threads is set up to execute the loop individually.  The loop basically uses the values of `foo` on every `Body` (apart from the one in question) to update the value of `bar` on the body in question.  So essentially no writes are being done to the values of `foo` on each body, and the only reads being done on `bar` are localised to the thread controlling that particular body; in pseudocode, it looks like this:

```
//create team of threads, and then this section is executed by each thread separately
for each Body i
    for each Body j =/= i
        i.bar += (j.foo * 2);
    end for
end for
```

My question is whether this will, as I think it should, maintain the coherency of the cache?  Because as far as I see it, none of the threads are reaching for things that are being edited by the other threads, so it should be safe, I feel.  But This is quite an important point in the report that I need to write on this, so I want to be sure.

Thank you.

Comment: It is difficult to verify whether you understand on how to correctly use OpenMP from the pseudocode only. Could you please update this to actual C++ with actual `#pragma omp`? Preferably also with a definition of `Body`. I know you already have an answer, but I feel it would be possible to respond more specifically to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rule is you need synchronization if you have more than one thread and at least one of them is a writer and the threads are accessing the same object.  If all of your threads are reading then you do not need any synchronization at all.

With an array/vector if you are writing to it but each thread is writing to its own unique section then you do not need any synchronization either as you are not accessing the same underlying objects (as long as you are not modifying the vector itself like adding or removing elements).  The only hazard with this is [false sharing](https://web.archive.org/web/20200302130554/https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads).  If two threads are working on the different parts of the array but they happen to be on the same cache line then any modification is going to dirty the cache line and both threads will be impacted.  This is just a performance impact though and does not lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt answer!  I'll keep in mind not to mess with the array/vector itself, and I'll have an eye open for the false sharing performance impact, to see if it has a significant effect on my program.

Comment: I have a problem with the use of the term *variable* in this answer. *Memory region* or *storage location*. Also you are not considering scenarios where the order of writes and their visibility matters.