# Is it possible to use threads if they have to write on the same vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have to solve the heat equation with a SDE.
The program runs correctly but it is very slow.

In a short way: i wrote a program, thats sets many particles randomly on a vector and moves them for some timesteps. 
After the time t, one counts all particles in each grid bin and saves this number in a counting-vector. Now i have to do `runs`=1000 for a good result. (The functions belong to a class).

```
void makeruns(const int runs){
  for(int i=0; i<runs; ++i){
      setandmove();
  }
}

void setandmove(){
    for(int t=0; t<timesteps; ++t){
       //set new particles and move particles on the grid
    }
    //Endposition is saved in the list Y_omega

    //count number of points in bins
    for(auto it=Y_omega.begin(); it!=Y_omega.end(); ++it){
        double valf = it->first;
        double vals = it->second;
        auto it_f =    std::lower_bound(intervall.begin(),intervall.end(),valf, [](auto P, auto V) -> bool {return P< V;});
        auto it_s = std::lower_bound(intervall.begin(),intervall.end(),vals, [](auto P, auto V) -> bool {return P < V;});

        int dist1 = std::distance(intervall.begin(),it_f);
        int dist2 = std::distance(intervall.begin(),it_s);

        count.at(dist1 + s*dist2)=count.at(dist1 + s*dist2) + 1;
    }
    Y_omega.clear();
}
```

Is it possible to make threads, at least for the first section or will they collide when they write on the vector  `count`

```
std::thread t1(makeruns, 250);
std::thread t2(makeruns, 250);
std::thread t3(makeruns, 250); 
std::thread t4(makeruns, 250);

t4.join();
t3.join();
t2.join();
t1.join();
```

Sadly i am not versed in threading.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'd have to synchronize the access however. Which may end up not giving you any performance boost.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068201/if-i-make-a-piece-of-code-in-which-each-thread-modifies-completely-different-par/41068285#41068285

Comment: Threading is a good way to introduce subtle bugs.  It is therefor worth trying to keep things as simple as possible, sufficiently simple that it is clear there can be no bugs.  Note: if the threads are all busy, there is no advantage to having more threads than there are cores on your machine (which is what you are doing).  I suggest making each thread have it's *own* grid, and count array - and then at the end of the run, grab a mutex, quickly add the local count into the global count, and release the mutex.

Comment: Start by getting rid of the noise in the code. Those calls to `lower_bound` with a lambda do exactly the same things as calling `lower_bound` without a function object. And `count.at(dist1 + s*dist2)=count.at(dist1 + s*dist2) + 1;` can be simply `++count[dist1 + s*dist2];` Sure, you can invoke magic compilers that will get rid of the waste here, but if you don't put it in to begin with then you know it's not there.

Comment: From the code I cannot find the vector that needs to be shared with the 4 instances of the problem. Is it only the counting-vector that needs to be shared?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. Yes only the counting vector needs to be shared. So the best thing would be if i thread class-objects, that call the memberfunctions? so then there are different Y_omega vectors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If multiple threads are going to be reading **and** writing to the same data locations, the code has to synchronize those accesses. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

As Martin Bonner mentioned in a note, one way to do that is to have each thread keep its own statistics separately, and combine the various thread results at the end.

Another way to do it is with atomic variables. If the `count` array holds `std::atomic<int>` instead of plain `int` (or whatever your count data type actually is), then the code as written, with one change, will work just fine: replace

```
count.at(dist1 + s*dist2)=count.at(dist1 + s*dist2) + 1;
```

with

```
++count.at(dist1 + s*dist2);
```

or

```
++count[dist1 + s*dist2];
```

The choice of which approach to take depends intimately on the nature of the data that's being processed.

Comment: @TobySpeight -- good point, thanks. I mentioned that in a comment to the question, but should mention it here. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are using a vector to insert result after each calculation, what you need is to make sure that only one thread performs insertion operation on the vector at a time. Since insertion operation is not very complex, blocking other threads while inserting won't have time penalty.

The best way would be to use a mutex object;

```
std::mutex m; // may be a global object or may be shared by a using a pointer.
Vector counting_vector; //some vector object for keeping result of each computation.

void threadWorker(int count){
     //here
    //create vector that will be used for set and move operation. Each thread will have it's own vector.
    while(count-->0){

        //perform the set and move operation on the vector;
        result=;/*the computed result*/
        m.lock();
        //code between lock() and unlock() won't run concurrently.
        counting_vector.insert(result);//insert or push_back into the vector
        m.unlock();

    }

}
```

Comment: You may find less contention by accumulating results into a per-thread vector, then locking `counting_vector` just once to accumulate all the results into it.